# Is there a way to change(increase) the half-second pause time for Watson speech to text recognize API

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

As per the Watson Speech To Text documentation when the 'continuous' parameter is set to false(which is default), "the service stops transcription at the first pause, which is denoted by a half-second of non-speech". Is there a way to change this half-second to a higher time period say 2 seconds (or some other configurable value)?

Comment: Hello, we do not currently have that feature available. What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. We have an web app which starts listening, when user clicks on a mic icon and we want to auto submitted the  transcribed text as soon the user stops talking a a pause is detected. To do this we set the `continuous=false` on the recognize API (we are using wss) which has a half second pause detection. We would like to give user more than the half second pause time in case they haven't finished.

Comment: You can set continuous=false and then a series of hypotheses will come to you as the user speaks. You can detect longer pauses by requesting timestamps from the service ('timestamps' parameter), and then react accordingly. This is how timestamps look like: "timestamps": [ [ "we", 1067.73, 1068.03 ] ] would that work for you?

Comment: @DanielBolanos It's been a while since you responded to this question - are there still no plans to add that feature?  I'm running into an issue combining STT and TTS. TTS starts the conversation, the user answers (STT) then TTS responds with another question. The response audio that is played to the user (TTS) has a slight pause in it and STT seems to be picking up the latter part of the response as microphone input. That triggers SST to think the user said something and it goes into a loop between TTS and STT. I'm working on alternatives but extending the EOS would sure help.

Comment: @DanielBolanos Never mind. I thought this through a bit more and the EOS is not the problem. I need to restructure the interplay between TTS and STT so that the essentially the microphone is off while the TTS audio is playing.

Comment: Hi @LWK69, I'm glad you figured that out :)